# bash - isolating uppercase words

Tags: bash, find, search, stack

So, I have a directory containing around 50 directories having for name 3 letter uppercase words:
AXC BCC EFC

amongst other directories.

I have already done a find to seek these 3 letter directories and store them in a list

```
list=`find /data/opr/ucansit/ -type d -name "???"`
```

The current output i get from an `echo ${list[@]}` is

```
/data/opr/ucansit/CUG /data/opr/ucansit/TGV /data/opr/ucansit/PAS
```

what i need now is seek the 3 letter directory names and store them in a stack as:

```
CUG
TGV
PAS
```

Note: I just need the names of the directories (the 3 letters)

BRegards,

Comment: If you don't need recursive, then `(cd /data/opr/ucansit; set -- ???; printf '%s\n' "$@")` is ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

```
list=$(find /tmp /data/opr/ucansit/ -type d -name "???" -exec basename {} \;)
printf "%s\n" "${list[@]}"
```

Comment: `find /tmp /data/opr/ucansit/ -type d -name "???" -printf "%f\n"`

Comment: Perfect . Exactly what I needed!

Comment: @Costas Beware that "-printf" only works if GNU find is used.